# pecl oAuth extension required

Tags: php, pecl

I am trying to use the Google AdWords API and have the entire directory uploaded. I have received the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ValidationException' with message 
     'Validation failed for [oauthHandlerClass] with value []:  
      Pecl OAuth extension is required to use OAuth 1. 
      Or a custom OAuth handler can be specified in settings.ini. '
```

I am using GoDaddy for FTP/Hosting. How do I get this "Pecl OAuth extension" and if not not how would I go about creating a custom oAuth handler to get rid of this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pecl OAuth is in C so you had to compile it on server but only server admin can do this.

You could try version in pure PHP - [OAuth for PHP from Google](https://code.google.com/p/oauth/)

Comment: GoDaddy does not offer a PHP Pecl extension. I downloaded the PECL directory and looked through it but I'm not quite sure what to do with it. Is it impossible using GoDaddy (shared server) or am I missing something?

Comment: Pecl version is in C (see files with .c and .h extension) so it needs to be compiled on server - but you can't do this on shared server - only GoDaddy admin can. So you have to use [pure PHP version](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/). There are examples how to use it in your code. By the way - I found another OAuth version on Google AdWords API - [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2). It  should be better to work with Google products.

Comment: @furas Hello sir, how can i install oAuth in my GoDaddy VPS Server? I searched a lot but there is no solution, can you pls help me?